# Accessing dd/mm/yy to calculate the total amount of sales per year?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, analysis

Edit: Re-structured the whole question for it to make more sense (I think?)

Here is the dataframe I am trying to analyse (or as close as I could make).

```
Customer_ID = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
Sales_Info = [11,22,33,44,55,66,77]
begin_date = '2019-10-16'
df = pd.DataFrame({'Customer_ID':Customer_ID,'Sales_Info':units,'Purchase_Date':pd.date_range(begin_date, periods=len(units))})
print (df.head(10))
```

Alternatively, here is a screenshot of what it looks like: [enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lYOt.png

I am trying to add all the Sales_Info over each fiscal year.

Obviously the data set has many more values than this but its the best example I could create. So far my coding knowledge is probably limited to **BASIC** as best, but I am trying to learn and would appreciate any help.

I have tried some of the below examples but I am stuggling to get any resulting outputs correct myself but I appreciate everyone's trying to help me and thankyou in advance.

Comment: Use `pandas.to_datetime(df.Date, format="%d/%m/%Y").dt.year` as grouping variable

Comment: I have edited the above, basically I am trying to add up the Sales_Info by each year, but the dataset contains multiple days and months which I need to organise and return the Sales_Info for each year individually. @user17242583.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly how you are using your data and how it's formatted but a pretty easy way to sum all sales_info for a year would look something like this:

```
data = [{"id": 1 "date": "11/12/2020", "Sales_info": 2}, ...]
yearly_sum = {}
for datum in data:
    year = datum["date"].split("/")[-1]
    if year in yearly_sum.keys():
         yearly_sum[year] += datum["Sales_info"]
    else:
         yearly_sum[year] = datum["Sales_info"]
```

essentially, check each entry for which year it belongs to, add to a year->salesinfo dictionary. Note that the code is untested so it might not work as it is.